# Вывод на экран считанной информации из файла C++

Tags: c++, fstream, getter, binary-file, ifstream

Есть программа которая либо записывает в файл либо считывает его , в файле содержатся объекты одного класса записываю я класс в файл так
`fs.write((char*)&obj,sizeof(Class));`

а считываю так

`fs.read((char*)&obj,sizeof(Class));`

как мне вывести информацию на экран(область видимости класса распространяется на всю программу)? И могу ли я использовать getter класса для того чтобы достать часть данных из того, что я считал? Или для этого придётся считывать информацию из файла по-другому? Класс состоит из POD типов, хоть это класс в котором есть другие классы, но тоже с POD типами)

Comment: Начнем с того, **что** такое ваш `Class`. Это POD или нет? Может, его вообще нельзя вот так читать-писать... Если можно - то все, у вас нормальный, обычный объект класса, работа с которым ничем не отличается от объекта, созданного с помощью обычного конструктора, например...

Comment: Как это понимать? - "либо читает файл либо считывает его "?

Comment: @ВЛ80 Исправил, спасибо